# How to divide a webpage into 3 scrollable parts using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a screenshot of an image that show three grey scrollbars. How do you recreate it using flutter.[image: Screenshot of an image]

Comment: Your screenshot is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

If yes, you can achieve it with a `Row` containing `ListViews`, `GridViews`, `SingleChildScrollViews`, or other scrollable widgets.

You will see that I embedded my `ListViews` and `GridView` inside `ScrollBar` widgets. I also associated a `ScrollController` to both the `Scrollbars` and the associated `ListView` or `GridView` and defined the `ScrollBar` as `isAlwaysShown: true`.

### Full source code for easy copy-paste

```
import 'dart:math' show Random;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final random = Random();
    final _leftScrollController = useScrollController();
    final _middleScrollController = useScrollController();
    final _rightScrollController = useScrollController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Scrollbar(
              controller: _leftScrollController,
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              child: ListView(
                controller: _leftScrollController,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: List.generate(
                  20,
                  (index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text('Left $index'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Scrollbar(
              controller: _middleScrollController,
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              child: GridView.count(
                controller: _middleScrollController,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                children: List.generate(
                  20,
                  (index) => AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 2 / 3,
                    child: ColoredBox(
                      color: Color(0xff555555 + random.nextInt(0x777777)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Scrollbar(
              controller: _rightScrollController,
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              child: ListView(
                controller: _rightScrollController,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: List.generate(
                  30,
                  (index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text('Right $index'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. It can help. Thank you!